# replace all dots in filenames with underscore

Tags: rename, filenames

I have a directory with some subdirectories with filenames and directorynames that contain some dots:

```
$ ls -R
.:
dir  file.with.dots

./dir:
subdir.with.dots

./dir/subdir.with.dots:
other.file
```

I really struggle to catch all these files with `find` because I don't want to rename the current folder `.` and `..` itself.

I also read how to [Replace dots with underscores in filenames, leaving extension intact](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56771/replace-dots-with-underscores-in-filenames-leaving-extension-intact), but that doesn't really fit here, because the main problem is the recursive selection of the files.

I tried to replace the dots with `find` and `tr`:

```
find $(pwd) -depth -name '*.*'|while read f; do mv -iv "$f" '"'$(echo $f|tr '.' '_')'"' ; done
```

but this would give errors if in both, the path to the file and the file itself, contains dots

How do I rename and replace all occurrences of a dot with an underscore?

Comment: WARNING: In any event you should check that the destination filename does NOT exist prior to doing the mv.  Otherwise, you might be removing something you needed to keep.

Comment: @mdpc: ok, now `mv -iv` will ask interactively if it should overwrite. But my try isn't good anyway, there is already a great answer below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv
zmv '(**/)(*.*)' '$1${2//./_}'
```

Otherwise, if you have access to `bash` (though `ksh93` or `zsh` will do as well), you could always do:

```
find . -depth ! -name '.*' -name '*.*' -exec bash -c '
  for file do
    dir=${file%/*}
    base=${file##*/}
    mv -i -- "$file" "$dir/${base//./_}"
  done' sh {} +
```

(though you'll miss the sanity checks done by `zmv`).

Those (intentionally) don't rename hidden files.

The point is to process the list depth-first (which `zmv` does by default, and using `-depth` in `find`) and only rename the basename of the file.

So that you do:

```
mv -- a.b/c.d a.b/c_d
```

and *then*:

```
mv -- a.b a_b
```

Also note that for the non-zmv solution, if you have a `a.b` file and a `a_b` directory in the same directory, then `mv -- a.b a_b` will happily move `a.b` *into* `a_b/`. To avoid that, if on a GNU system, you can add the `-T` option to `mv`.

---

As I see you tried to edit the answer to use a `while read` loop.

Note that you should generally avoid `while read` loops, even in this case where one command per line has to be run anyway. If you really want to use one, then doing it right is tricky and involves ksh/bash/zshisms:

```
{
  find . -depth ! -name '.*' -name '*.*' -exec printf '%s\0' {} + |
    while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
      dir=${file%/*}
      base=${file##*/}
      mv -i -- "$file" "$dir/${base//./_}"
    done <&3 3<&-
} 3<&0
```

(you can replace `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +` with `-print0` if your find supports it).

You need:

- `-print0`/`-exec printf '%s\0' {} +` as you can't rely on newline as the separator since newline is a valid character in a filename
- as a result, you need `-d ''` (`read` reads until NUL instead of NL)
- `IFS=` (that is remove all the whitespace characters from `IFS` for `read` as otherwise strips them from the end of the input record).
- `-r` as otherwise `read` treats backslash as an escape character (for the field and record separator).
- *that litte dance with file descriptors* because you want the standard input of `mv` to be the terminal (for the answers to the `-i` prompts), not the pipe from `find`.

Comment: what is the `--` in mv stand for? and it seems like the `-i` option for interactive doesnt work here.

Comment: `--` is a good habit to have. It marks the end of options. It's not needed here as all file paths start with `./` (and thus not `-` so can't be taken as options). `zmv` always calls `mv -- ...` as well.

Comment: `-i` prompts you before overwriting a file (losing data). I added it here because we're not benefiting from the kind of sanity check that `zmv` does _prior_ to start the job. `-i` would give you a chance to avoid a big mistake.

Comment: I know about the interaction, but there is no question at my testserver using `-i`

Comment: @rubo77, you'd only get a question if for instance you had both a `a.b` and `a_b` in a given directory (though not if `a_b` itself is a directory as the `mv -i -- a.b a/b` would move `a.b` inside `a_b` (see the (GNU-specific) `-T` option to mv to avoid that))

Comment: Why not using `while read file` instead of the `find -exec`? `find . -depth ! -name '.*' -name '*.*' -type d |while read file; do      dir=${file%/*};     base=${file##*/};     mv -i -- "$file" "$dir/${base//./_}"; done
`

Comment: @rubo77 See my edit. `while read` loops are generally bad shell scripting practice.

Comment: Great answer! I would just add `-v` for verbose to all `mv` commands

Comment: @rubo77, add it if your `mv` command supports it but many `mv` commands don't as that's not standard. `zmv` does support `-v` though (regardless of which `mv` is invoked).